# C++/CLI fstream in the static library prevents winform program to run

Tags: c++-cli

I made my own static library which contain classes. I want to use it in a windows form application. I can link the library and successfully run the program. But if i include a header from library, the program doesn't show anything. The window does not pop up. I investigated it and i found that if the library contains fstream object, the issue happens. The picture is from the static library. What can i do?[image: Th]

Comment: Not nearly enough detail here to be of any use. You say you are writing a Winforms app; presumably you are doing that in C#. If not, why the hell not? C++/CLI for interop with unmanaged code.

Comment: Both library and the winforms app are written in C++/CLI. If i include any header from library the window doesn't popup despite there is no error. The problem is happening when the library contain any kind of fstream object.

Answer (score 0):

I made all fstream objects in the library to static(for example 'static ifstream file') and the issue solved. I don't know why.